# Add subscriber to a chatter feed on a parent object

Tags: apex, trigger, entitysubscription

I am new to Apex, and I was hoping that I could get help.
My goal is to auto subscribe a user to chatter on parent object. For example, I have two object, `Story`, and `Story Task`. `Story` is the parent object and `Story task` is the child. `Story` has the chatter feed enabled, `Story Task` does not. What I am trying to achieve is that if an `Owner__c` is populated on `Story_Task__c` then update the parent object `Story__c` chatter feed by subscribing the Story Task's Owner to the Story's chatter feed.

Here is something I have created, but not exactly sure how I can assign the owner to update the parent's chatter feed. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
trigger StoryTaskOwnerChatterSubscription on Story_Task__c (after insert, after undelete) {
        List<EntitySubscription> stEntitySubList = new List<EntitySubscription>();

        if(Trigger.isInsert){
            for(Story_Task__c stt:trigger.new){
                List<Story__c> story = new List<Story__c>();

                List<Story_Task__c> stask =[Select SubscriberId From Story_Task__c Where id =:story.Id];

                if(task.Owner__c != Null){
                    EntitySubscription stEntity = new EntitySubscription();
                    stEntity.ParentId = stask.Id;
                    stEntity.SubscriberId = stask.Owner__c;
                    stEntitySubList.add(stEntity);      
                }

            }

            insert stEntitySubList;
        }
}
```

Comment: Does the trigger you have work? How does the behavior you observe differ from that you expect?

Comment: Not it does not. I essentially get a message saying that I can not perform this action as Story_Task__c does not have chatter feed enabled. This makes me think that my code is trying to assign the owner to the Story_Task_c chatter feed instead of Story's feed. That is why I am thinking that I am not specifying correctly that I want to update the parent object Story's entity subscription.

Comment: Please include your error message here ***verbatim***. Error message text makes your posts significantly more specific and well defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't query in a loop. Never.

Second, if you're trying to subscribe someone to the parent `Story__c` feed, you need to set that as the `ParentId` on the `EntitySubscription` record.

```
List<EntitySubscription> subscriptions = new List<EntitySubscription>();
for (Story_Task__c task : trigger.new)
{
    subscriptions.add(new EntitySubscription(
        ParentId = task.Story__c, SubscriberId = task.Owner__c
    ));
}
insert subscriptions;
```

Note that instantiating an `SObject` record via `name=value` pairs in the constructor is significantly faster than instantiating it and then setting each field individually.

You might need to add de-duplication to your approach, but I'm not entirely sure on that.